# How do I save a coffee damaged wasp?

Tags: zoology

I found a wasp in one of my coffee cups about 1 hour ago. There was barely any coffee left but it had managed to get itself pretty much drenched in coffee. I took it out. Put it on a piece of paper and put a pile of sugar next to it. It started eating but it was in a pretty bad state. I came back half an hour later to check up on it and it had fallen down on the floor. It's state seemed to have worsened. Went from walking around to lying still and moving it's limbs.

What kind of damage did it suffer from the coffee and how would I go about maximizing it's chances for survival?

Comment: D'awwwwwwwww :)

Comment: Unfortunately this has gathered quite a few close votes for being off topic (presumably due to [veterinary medicine advice being out of scope](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/204/vet-medicine-questions)) and *one rather **mean** 'Too Localised'* (:P)  - the poor wasp may have passed out of this world before we'd drafted a rescue plan - sorry :-)

Comment: ah yes, it's understandable. The question was quite immature. The wasp was dead by dawn (or that's when I woke up and threw the corpse out).